# pygame.time.set_timer() event reset?

Tags: python, timer, pygame

I've got a little question...

Is there a reset of some sort for the pygame.time.set_timer()?

I've got it running okay but the issue is that I need the timer to reset back to 0 whenever a certain action is performed. As it's running now, the timer will trigger the *movedownauto* event every second(no matter what happens), but what I want it to do is reset when a key is pressed so that it will then wait one second AFTER the key is pressed to trigger the *movedownauto* event. 
It would be ideal if something could be put into the *if event.type == USEREVENT:* section.

Example below ↓

```
pygame.time.set_timer(USEREVENT, 1000)

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        # Figure out if it was an arrow key. If so
        # adjust speed.
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_speed = -40
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_speed = 40
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_speed = 40

        # User let up on a key
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        # If it is an arrow key, reset vector back to zero
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_speed = 0
            elif event.key == event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_speed = 0
        # Move the object according to the speed vector.
        x_coord += x_speed
        y_coord += y_speed

        if event.type == USEREVENT:
            movedownauto(screen, x_coord, y_coord)
        else:
            drawcharacter(screen, x_coord, y_coord)



    clock.tick(tickspeed)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to trigger the `USEREVENT` only once after a keypress, remove the `pygame.time.set_timer(USEREVENT, 1000)` line from the top and add `pygame.time.set_timer(USEREVENT, 1000, True)` inside the `elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:` block.

If you set the third argument of `pygame.time.set_timer` to `True`, the event will be added to the event queue only once (note that this feature is only avaiable in pygame version 2)

If you want the `USEREVENT` to happen regulary and just "reset" the timer if a `KEYDOWN` happens, just remove the timer and add it again.

```
elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    pygame.time.set_timer(USEREVENT, 0)
    pygame.time.set_timer(USEREVENT, 1000)
    ...
```

Comment: for some reason the timer only accepts two arguments and screams errors at me when i put `pygame.time.set_timer(USEREVENT, 1000, True)`

Comment: @AbramLiddell yeah, sorry, that third argument is only avaiable in the newer pygame versions; you're probably using version 1.9.

Comment: Why did pygame remove the third argument on python 3?